# Audio Engineを使用した音源の自動再生について

Tags: swift

お世話になっております．
Swiftを使用してアプリを開いたら音が自動でなるコード実装したいのですが，以下の様に作ったところ音が再生されません．
AVAudioPlayerの場合は再生が可能だったのでAudio Engineの使い方に問題があると思っております．
コード自体は回ってしまいます．

お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします．

```
import UIKit
import Accelerate
import CoreAudioKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioFile:AVAudioFile!
    var PCMBuffer:AVAudioPCMBuffer!
    var address:String?
    var buffer:[[Float]]! = Array<Array<Float>>()
    var samplingRate:Double?
    var nChannel:Int?
    var nframe:Int?
        
    let url = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("ファイル名.wav")

    //最初からあるメソッド
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAudioData()
        // bluetooth接続用
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .setCategory(.playAndRecord,
                         mode: .voiceChat,
                         options: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
    }

    
    func loadAudioData(){
            //オーディオファイルを読み込み、データをaudioFileに格納
            let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
            let engine = AVAudioEngine()
            self.audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
            self.samplingRate = self.audioFile.fileFormat.sampleRate
            self.nChannel = Int(self.audioFile.fileFormat.channelCount)
            self.nframe = Int(self.audioFile.length)
            self.PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: self.audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(self.nframe!))
            try! self.audioFile.read(into: self.PCMBuffer)
            
            engine.attach(player)
            engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: self.PCMBuffer.format)
        
            do {
              // エンジンの開始
              try engine.start()
              // プレイヤーの再生
              player.play()
            } catch let error {
              print(error)
            }
            
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

大きく2つの問題点があります。

1. `AVAudioEngine`がローカル変数になっている
2. `AVAudioPlayerNode`に対して、せっかく作成した`AVAudioPCMBuffer`を再生するよう設定していない

`AVAudioEngine`のインスタンスは、`AVAudioEngine`の動作中(再生中)はずっとどこかに強参照で保持されていないといけません。`ViewController`クラスのインスタンスプロパティにしておくのが適切でしょう。

(一方、`audioFile`から`nframe`までのインスタンスプロパティは、なぜインスタンスプロパティなのか理解できませんでした。以下のコード例では、それらのインスタンスプロパティは削除して、ローカル変数にしています。何か別の処理で使用するために必要なら適宜書き換えて下さい。ついでに言うと、Implicitly Unwrapped Optionalと通常Optionalの使い分けの基準も不明です…。)

```
    let engine = AVAudioEngine() //<-1.
    
    func loadAudioData() {
        //オーディオファイルを読み込み、データをaudioFileに格納
        let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        do {
            let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
            let nframe = audioFile.length
            guard let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(nframe)) else {
                print("Failed creating AVAudioPCMBuffer")
                return
            }
            try audioFile.read(into: pcmBuffer)
            
            engine.attach(player)
            engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: pcmBuffer.format)
            
            player.scheduleBuffer(pcmBuffer, completionHandler: nil) //<-2.
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
        do {
            // エンジンの開始
            try engine.start()
            // プレイヤーの再生
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

(強制アンラップや強制tryを使用していた部分も書き換えました。「自分には理解できない挙動をする(可能性がある)」と言う場合に、それらを使用するべきではありません。)

再生するのに不要なコードは削除してあります。また、`scheduleBuffer`ではなく、`scheduleFile`を使えばもう少し短くなりますが、`AVAudioPCMBuffer`を使う意図がよくわからないので、そこはそのままにしてあります。

`//<-1.`と `//<-2.`で示した修正以外は今回の事象に関して本質的なものではありませんが、出来る限り「予想外の事態が発生した場合に得られる情報を黙って捨てない」ようなコーディングを心がけられた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます．細かい文法の指摘までありがとうございます． 依然として音が鳴らず， engine.connect(player, to: engine.outputNode, format: pcmBuffer.format) のところで以下の様なエラーが出ます． [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000391bf00> 調べたところAVAudioPlayerにおおいて解決方法が見られますが，AVAudioPlayerNodeを用いる場合はどの様に対処すれば良いかわからない状況です． 度々の質問で申し訳ございません． よろしくお願いします． –

Comment: @Nesage さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。`No factory registered for`については、正常に再生音が出力される場合にも出てくるメッセージなので無視しておいて下さい。音が鳴らない、については回答に示したコードそのままで動作確認していますので、その他の設定や環境周りが関係あるのかもしれません。とりあえず、`setCategory`で`.playAndRecord`を指定しておられますが、Info.plistにはマイク使用の記述を追加されましたでしょうか？

Comment: さらなるお返事ありがとうございます．マイク使用を許可し，`loadAudioData`を`try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()`の後に持って行ったら再生されました．

Comment: @Nesage さん、ご確認ありがとうございます。こちらの環境で音が出たのでそれでよしとしてしまいましたが、`setCategory`を実行する順序はその方が良さそうですね。今後参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。